# Semigroups: Product Rule

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Banach space $E$.

Consider C0-semigroups:
$$S,T:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathcal{B}(E)$$

Then the product rule holds:
$$(TS)'(t)x=T'(t)S(t)x+T(t)S'(t)x$$
How to prove this from scratch?

Comment: A little bit of notational clarification would be rather nice.

Comment: @Ian: Sure, where can I help?

Comment: Labeling $\mathcal{H}$ was the main confusion (I was confused as to whether $H^*$ was the dual space of the Hilbert space or the adjoint of the Hamiltonian). Explaining that also explained that $\mathcal{D}$ means "domain of". So now it is pretty clear. I assume you're writing down the derivative of $A_t$ with respect to $t$?

Comment: @Ian: Ah good you mentioned: Yes that may cause confusion.

Comment: That denotes the domain of the selfadjoint operator, a.k.a. Hamiltonian.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. I think it is clear now.

Comment: Some people here on MSE seem to appear over again and again closing threads all the time and the worst about it without any productive contribution or constructive critique. Honestly: Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper estimate gives:
$$\|\frac{1}{h}\{T(r+h)S(r+h)x-T(r)S(r)x\}-T'(r)S(r)x-T(r)S'(r)x\|\\
\leq\|T\|_{[r-\varepsilon,r+\varepsilon]}\|\frac{1}{h}\{S(r+h)x-S(r)x\}-S'(r)x\|\\
+\|\frac{1}{h}\{T(r+h)S(r)x-T(r)S(r)x\}-T'(r)S(r)x\|\\+\|T(r+h)S'(r)x-T(r)S'(r)x\|\to0$$
*(Note that boundedness on compacta was crucial!)*